# Prohibition of transfer to mobile numbers

Tags: asterisk

Sorry for my bad english.
I use asterisk + frepbь. My task is to make sure that employees can not make the transfer of the call to mobile numbers. It's about transfer, not about calls directly. When, by example, one caller calls another, the latter should not be able to make a call transfer to the mobile number.
Help please solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any dialplan in TRANSFER_CONTEXT variable.

After that you have deal yourself in detecting if number is mobile in dialplan.

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variables

Comment: it is possible to make it through freepbx?

Comment: Via web - no. Via files ovveride - yes

Comment: himself a novice in this matter
you can help in this matter